# Is it ever a bad idea to let a potential employer know you're talking to other potential employers?

Tags: interviewing

It seems like every once in a while a potential employer will get a little irritated with me when I let them know I'm talking to other people, typically because they asked or because they ask me about availability at a time when I have another interview and I just flat out tell them I'm talking to somebody else at that time.

Should I just regard the phenomenon as sort of a convenient accidental filter keeping me away from the crazy people work cultures or should I try to avoid giving more details than necessary (I've been known to do this occasionally) whenever it comes up for some reason? I certainly don't see how it works out as a bad thing for me for them to know they've got competition if I'm not trying too hard to let them know but I am after all, a nerd, and a bit socially thick at times.

I'm primarily a client-side web and JavaScript developer in Chicago where the market is pretty strong so it shouldn't really be a surprise or suspicious that I'm actually dealing with multiple potential opportunities at any given time.

Answer (score 3):

**Nobody wants nobody that nobody wants.**

That means that if you are in an "in-demand" career field and you aren't being approached by others, the perception may be that there is something "wrong" with you or your work performance. That's ***not*** a good perception for potential employers to have.

Be honest about it: If you are asked if you have been approached by other employers, then simply state that you have. There's no need to go into detail, as a few unscrupulous recruiters might use the knowledge that you are being interviewed for a position to interject another of their candidates into the "mix." Simply state that you have been approached by others seeking candidates.

Don't lie about things, because if you are in a small industry and you mention or hint that a certain employer is interested and the recruiter knows that company isn't hiring, you may damage a personal relationship which you may need later.

Recruiters are contacting you because their clients **need** employees. If you are looking for a new position and you have several opportunities on your plate, be honest about that as it may cause the recruiter to "sweeten" the deal if their client is looking for someone with your experience and skill sets.

Answer (score 2):

it is  not bad idea. But it is suggested to avoid that situation

Every potential employer seeks
- Your time and availability for discussions to go through interview process and make offer
- Your interest on the project or their organizations
- Finally wish to you to join with them once they like you.

Below are the suggestions.

**Prioritize your potential Opportunities:** Prioritization really helps. Prioritize based on how best the opportunities meet your expectations. Obviously you can focus on highly prioritized opportunities. The catch here is those opportunities should be achievable. If your skill set is barely matching and you have less capabilities to grab that opportunity better to give less priority

**Try to deal one opportunity at a time and plan to avoid conflicts:** It is always advisable to deal one opportunity at a time and avoid conflicts. Discuss about the interview process, how many rounds involved and potentially how much time it takes at initial discussion it self. Based on that you can schedule and give time to other potential employers. And for a given week or period estimate your availability for given opportunity. And honestly tell them

**Act based on the priority of opportunites:** Generally when ever conflicts occurs you can give more preference to the high priority opportunities than other opportunities. When ever conflict occurs in terms of time and date politely request employer why rated low priority to defer it later time. If it is not workable check with the other employer(who has high priority) whether they can defer if possible and act accordingly.

**When ever Employer asks about other opportunities:** Don’t lie. Tell them that you are trying with other opportunities also. However also tell them your their priority in your list if they are top in your list. If not tell them what makes you to incline and take decision over other employers. For example “If the project has better growth, and better role for me, I will give priority to that organization”.

Comment: Well even I'm not socially inept enough to tell somebody they're my "backup" : ) But more seriously you suggest an interesting point about them wanting that decision to bring someone on to be immediate with no further complications coming from your side of it once their mind is made up. That's the attitude of an employer I'd probably be better off offending in the long term so long as I have choices.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to say that.

They're talking to other candidates, and you're talking to other companies.  Everyone knows all of this.

You may be their "4th choice," but they're never going to tell you that.  They may be your "4th choice," but you should never tell them that.

They know you could accept another offer, and you know they could accept another candidate.  Anyone who believes otherwise is deluded.